# Was the chatas nasi brought by the Head of the Sanhedrin as well?

Tags: korban

In The Midrash Says Vayikra page 32 the author writes that the chatas nasi was brought by a Jewish king or Head of the Sanhedrin who sinned.  Is this correct, and if so is there any source for it?  I was under the possibly mistaken impression that only a King brought a chatas nasi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Mishnah Horayos* 3:3:**

https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Horayot.3.3

וְאֵיזֶהוּ הַנָּשִׂיא, זֶה הַמֶּלֶךְ, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (ויקרא ד) וְעָשָׂה אַחַת מִכָּל מִצְוֹת ה' אֱלֹהָיו, נָשִׂיא שֶׁאֵין עַל גַּבָּיו אֶלָּא ה' אֱלֹהָיו

*Who is meant by a ruler? A king; for it says, “Any of all the commandments of the Lord his God” (Leviticus 4:22), a ruler (king) who has none above him save the Lord his God.*

The *deresha* used implies that the requirement of *Nasi* is anyone at the top of societies' hierarchy - not necessarily a king.

***Gemara Horayos* 11b**

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%91

**בעא מיניה רבי מרבי חייא כגון אני מהו בשעיר אמר ליה הרי צרתך בבבל**

*Rebbi (Yehuda Hanasi) asked R' Chiya - someone like me, would he bring a goat? He said to him, "Your superior is in Bavel".*

As Rashi explains, were it not for the Exilarch in Bavel being superior to Rebbi, he would, despite not being a "king", have brought a *korban nasi*.

It's clear from the *Gemara *that any "head" would be a *nasi* for the purposes of the *korban*, as long as they are actually supreme.

The *Gemorah* then quotes a different version of Rebbi's question:

**רב ספרא מתני הכי בעא מיניה רבי מרבי חייא כגון אני מהו בשעיר א"ל התם שבט הכא מחוקק**

Rashi:

**התם שבט - דהיינו מקל כמו כי תכנו בשבט לא ימות
והכא מחוקק - חכם**

Rashi here explains that political power (a staff in the sense of a weapon) is required, not just being a teacher of law.

This second version implies that Rebbi was intrinsically excluded from *nasi*-hood, as he lacked the necessary political power (I assume being subservient to Roman governors).

However any leader with supreme political power, whether king or not, would be included. The *nasi* of the Sanhedrin may at times have held such power, and it's probably that type of leader which the book you quote refers to.